# Compute a new dataframe following specific set of rules

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with 4 columns

Dataframe 1:

```
 column_A column_B  column_C   id  
0       1       1      anna    123
1       2       1      anna      7
2      30       2      bob      42
3      20       2      bob      12
4      10       2      charlie   1
5     100       3      charlie   2
```

Now, I want to compute a new Dataframe (Dataframe 2) with the following properties

```
     id_1    id_2       val
0     123       7         1
1      42      12         1
2      42       1         2
3      12       1         2 
4       1       2         3
```

val == 1, if across rows **both corresponding values** in column_B and column_C match

val == 2, if across rows **only corresponding value** in column_B  match

val == 3, if across rows **only corresponding value** in column_C match

My current implementation is O(N^2). Considering the dataframe is large, is there some parallelization i can use to speed up the processing.

We can also interpret the Question as finding pair of row index in a Pandas Dataframe where value in column_B, column_C is same.
example: Row[0] and row[1] have same values in column_B and column_C

Comment: val == 1, if both values in column_B and column_C match
on what base you are looking for matching since frame are having different dTypes

Comment: Corresponding values match, such as in the example given corresponding values in column_B and column_C in row pair (0,1) and (2,3) match

Comment: sorry still, don't understand.

Comment: Dataframe 1 is the base dataframe, with id column as the identifier for each row.
Now i need to find pairs of Id's where corresponding values in column_B and Column_C match.

In the above example, row[0] and row[1] have the same corresponding values in column_B and column_C and hence, I created a new row in dataframe 2, such as (123,7,1)

Comment: How corresponding value of column_B and column_C can match? one is int other is string.

Comment: @krishna Corresponding values under the same column in a different row. Column_B value is 1 in both row[0] and row[1], similarly, column_C is "anna" in both row[0] and row[1]

Comment: sorry can't understand. You can take 1-2 rows of output dataframe and explain how they are obtained.

Comment: @krishna : Updated the question :
We can also interpret the Question as finding pair of row index in a Pandas Dataframe where value in column_B, column_C is same. example: Row[0] and row[1] have same values in column_B and column_C

Comment: Do you need Id_1 and Id_B column too or only extra val column is enough in existing dataframe ? and does checking happens within consecutive values (in columns) or across whole dataframe ?

Comment: We need Id_1 and Id_2 columns, and the number of row pairs can be more than the size of base dataframe

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be the following:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as it

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(list(it.combinations(df.id, 2))), columns=['id_1', 'id_2'])

    id_1  id_2
0    123     7
1    123    42
2    123    12
3    123     1
4    123     2
5      7    42
6      7    12
7      7     1
8      7     2
9     42    12
10    42     1
11    42     2
12    12     1
13    12     2
14     1     2

    rules = lambda x: abs(
     (df[df.id==x[0]].column_C.values == df[df.id==x[1]].column_C.values).all()*3 -
     (df[df.id==x[0]].column_B.values == df[df.id==x[1]].column_B.values).all()*2)

df2['val'] = df2.apply(rules, axis=1)

df2[df2.val>0]
   id_1  id_2  val
0   123     7    1
1    42    12    1
2    42     1    2
3    12     1    2
4     1     2    3
```

The idea is to calculate the absolute value of "if-C-match times 3 minus if-B-match times 2".
I.e.:
both match: `|3 - 2| = 1`
only C:     `|3 - 0| = 3`
only B:     `|0 - 2| = 2`
no match:     `|0 - 0| = 0`

It would be clearer if you requested one column match to be val=1, the other val=2 so the sum would have been 1+2=3, then the lambda formula would have been simpler ("if-B-match times 1 plus if-C-match times 2") - but this is just a matter of some simple operators and their order.